# PowerBI Service Performance small datasets vs single large dataset with row level security

Tags: powerbi

I am searching for answer on my below queries for PowerBI

While using powerBI service I have large dataset(PBIX file approx 5 GB) and I have given row level security to users , for example users from particular location can access only there location data.

I need to know how PowerBI service loads these PBIX files internally

1 PBIX file is attached to 1 Dashboard having multiple reports and  multiple users look at this dashboard simultaneously from different locations with row level security.

if 2 user open dashboard simultaneously (at the same time) does powerbi consume 10 GB of memory or it just loads the PBIX one in memory and serves each user request ?

I really don't have idea on internal working of PowerBI consider me as starter.

Comment: The data will have only one instance in memory, which will be filtered to show only the data, that the current user is allowed to see - so two users will query one dataset using two different filters.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov does it means if  loading several small datasets connected to multiple dashboards is equivalent to loading a big dataset with row level security connected to multiple datasets in terms of performance?

Comment: It depends a lot. This isn’t a question that can be answered in general.